# How to clone a type T in c#?

Tags: c#, types, ormlite-servicestack

I have a type `Foo` as follow:

```
[Alias("Boo")]
public class Foo
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I am saving the history of changes of the objects properties, and for performance reasons I would like to create a second table where to push all history. Unfortunately OrmLite does not support (afaik) multiple tables per type. The alias will simply be used instead of the type name when defined.

Since I am using generic data controllers, I need to **clone the actual type** `T` (with a different name `Boo`). I do not need to convert/cast objects between both types, but it would be helpful if that is possible as well.

Comment: So, whenever you make a change to `class Foo`, you want there to exist a `class Boo` with the same properties in it, saving some error-prone manual typing?

Comment: Sort of but I dont have control over the original classes plus some of them are generated at runtime again where I have no control (I guess it is using CodeDOM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned to be easier than I though - although did not cross my mind at the beginning : Inheritance!

As I do not have control over the `Foo` classes, I cannot just manually write a new type to reflect it (members may change in `Foo`). Creating a new type `Boo` that inherit from `Foo` with no extra members defined will allow both casting and table creation with a new name using OrmLite.

```
public class Foo
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Boo : Foo
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

"Cloning" an instance is pretty much ambiguous: is it a deep or shallow clone? If it's deep, how deep? Would it include references to other possible POCOs? If so, how would it include them? Using an id? Using a copy?

Also, storing full copies of the objects in a different table is just not the way to go for implementing history.

If I was you, I'd have either a different type that stores the serialized changes in time, then have a list of changes in your entity.

This is how I have implemented it in my POCOs for some recent project (using entity framework for persisting, adapt as necessary for OrmLite... also some things removed):

```
/* BaseEntity just adds "Id" and some other properties common to all my
   POCOs */
public class EntityHistory : BaseEntity
{
  /* ... Other properties removed for clarity ... */
  public Guid TransactionId { get; set; }
  public DateTime TransactionTime { get; set; }

  public string OldValues { get; set; }
  public string NewValues { get; set; }
}
```

Then have a base entity (or an interface, I use a base entity because I don't need extra multiple inheritance and saves me from writing the same property in all my classes) for those entities that need to store the history on:

```
public abstract class BaseTrackedEntity : BaseEntity, IAuditableEntity, IChangeTrackedEntity
{
  /* ... Other properties removed for clarity ... */
  public ICollection<EntityHistory> Histories { get; set; }
}
```

Then your entities would inherit from `BaseTrackedEntity`.

Upon persisting changes to the database, you'd find out the changes (it's easy in EF, which gives you a `ChangeSet`, don't know about OrmLite, but if it doesn't provide the means, you can just work it out using reflection), from your loaded entity to the saved one, and would serialize them to an `EntityHistory` instance (in `OldValues` and `NewValues`) and just add that to the `Histories` list. I use JSON but you could use whatever.

This works both for logging purposes (I haven't copied my logging properties -such as `User`, `CreationTime`, and stuff-, but they'd be on `BaseTrackedEntity`) and for `Undoing` (the `TransactionId` in `EntityHistory` groups undo stages if needed), it's quite performant (much more so than cloning and storing the whole object one time per update) and it's easy to implement and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Could you add and implement `IClonable<T>`?

```
interface ICloneable<T>
{
  T Clone();
}
[Alias("Boo")]
public class Foo : ICloneable<Foo>
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public Foo Clone() { ... }
}
```

Comment: Just a warning that it is sometimes ambiguous when you say `Clone`, as it's not clear whether it's deep or shallow copy. Even [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable(v=vs.110).aspx) says "we recommend that ICloneable not be implemented in public APIs."

Answer (score 0):

You can use Inheritance to clone the definition

Comment: I do not want an instance clone. I need the type definition cloned

Comment: Do you know about Inheritance.

Comment: Create a type inheriting from the one you want to clone the definition without defining further members may work

Comment: That just did not cross my mind! but that is a perfect solution (inheritance)! Edit your answer and I will accept it as the current one is a bit off.